# How to display PHP & HTML source code on a page?

Tags: php

How would one go about showing PHP code on user end. Sort of like [w3School](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/default.asp) does?

Having lets say a grey area div, and then showing the code in there without activating it?

Comment: Don't add the opening `<?php` tag

Comment: or closing tag either `?>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use html entities `&lt;?php` in the html it will be rendered as <?php

You can use [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to encode your code to use html entities.

Comment: +1 But you have to escape more than this. Also the `&` must be escaped for example: `if (x && y) {}`. So if the content is passed through PHP [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php) could help.

Comment: @insertusernamehere yes you'll have to use html entities for all characters that need escaping.

Answer (score 4):

Use `<pre>` or `<code>` tags to wrap your code.

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php to further see how you can make the code look pretty.

Since passing a large block of code to highlight_string() can be messy, you may want to look at output buffering in combination with highlight_string to output colorized php code.

Something like:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

phpinfo();
echo "this echo statement isn't executed";

<?php 
$code = ob_get_clean();
highlight_string($code);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can use following code to display php code on webpage.

```
highlight_string("<?php print('This is php code.'); ?>");
```

It will give output like

```
<?php print('This is php code.'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to not wrap that code in PHP tags.  So instead of this:

```
<?
    var sample = "code";
?>
```

You would have this:

```
var sample = "code";
```

It's not the code itself which triggers the server-side compile from the PHP engine, it's the tags which indicate to that engine what blocks of the file are code and what are not.  Anything that's not code is essentially treated as a string and output to the page as-is for the browser to interpret.

Once you're outputting the code, it's then a matter of formatting it.  The old standard is to wrap it in `pre` tags to get rid of HTML-ish formatting:

```
<pre>
var sample = "code";
</pre>
```

You can also apply CSS style to the `pre` tags (or any other tags you want to use for displaying code, such as `div`) as you see fit.

There are also very useful code syntax highlighting plugins and tools to make the code a lot "prettier".  [Google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) often comes highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

use the header function of php, this will rea

```
<?php
  header("content-type: text/plain");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done by showing code within `<pre>` or `<code>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this template........

```
######################################################################
echo "<h2><br>Source Code of ".basename((string)__FILE__) . "</h2><hr>";
show_source(__FILE__);
echo "<hr>";
echo "<h2>Output of ".basename((string)__FILE__) . "<hr></h2>";
#######################################################################
```

It will show the source code and output following.

Answer (score -2):

The PHP code will just be a string that you can `echo` or `print` onto the page, no different than any other data you want PHP to display for you. If you want to keep the formatting (ex. the indentation), put it inside a `<pre><code>` block.

Ex:

```
$php_code = '<?php $foo = bar; ?>';

echo "<pre><code>$php_code</code></pre>";
```

Comment: which will give you `'; echo "<pre><code>$php_code</code></pre>";` as ?> closes php and reports error on unclosed quotes

Comment: That's not actually true. I just ran my code and it worked as I described. Try it for yourself. EDIT: Actually, no, you're right and I'm wrong. It worked outside the <body> tag, (ex. as the title of the document), but nowhere else. So thank you, I honestly did not know that the PHP parser behaved that way.