# Output some PHP code into a HTML <code> tag

Tags: php, html, special-characters

How can I use the HTML `<code>` element to output a block of PHP code, without the page running that PHP code? Eg;

```
<pre><code>
    <?php
        // Some super duper PHP code
    ?>
</code></pre>
```

I'm creating an API docs page, which features snippets of PHP that anyone wishing to use the API can use as examples, but anything wrapped in `<?php>` tags runs as an actual PHP function

Comment: Try changing the <? to &#x3C;? and the ?> to ?&#x3E;, htmlentity encoding.  Maybe look at:  [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/show-php-code-on-site-without-php-executing-the-code/33586).  They also mention a library there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I display PHP code in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842575/how-do-i-display-php-code-in-html)

Comment: This type question already is there.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842575/how-do-i-display-php-code-in-html)[link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621630/how-to-display-php-html-source-code-on-a-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&lt;?php` and `?&gt;`.

The HTML entities will show up as PHP opening and closing tags when the page is rendered, but PHP will obviously not see them. But you have to html-escape your code anyways, otherwise contained HTML-tags will be rendered. So there should be

```
&lt;?php echo 'Hello, World.&lt;br&gt;'; ?&gt;
```

Another way would be to have a string specified by a [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) and then output html-escaped ([demo](https://eval.in/531304)):

```
<?php

$code = <<<'EOC'
<?php
echo 'Hello, World.<br>';
// ...your code here...
?>
EOC;

echo htmlentities($code);
?>
```

Have look for different approaches at [How do I display PHP code in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842575/how-do-i-display-php-code-in-html).

Comment: Works but isn't best practice for something like this

Comment: Ok and whats the best practice?

Answer (score 3):

Do this via PHP like so:

```
<?php

$code = '<?php
echo "Hello, World!";
?>';

echo '<code>' . htmlspecialchars($code) . '</code>';

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
<?php  echo '<?php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you.........

```
######################################################################
echo "<h2><br>Source Code of ".basename((string)__FILE__) . "</h2><hr>";
show_source(__FILE__);
echo "<hr>";
echo "<h2>Output of ".basename((string)__FILE__) . "<hr></h2>";
#######################################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert the less-than and greater-than to their HTML name.

```
<pre><code><?php echo
    "&lt;!--
    This is the church title to be used in the heading of the web-pages.
    Author: John Fischer III of Written For Christ in 2018
    Updated:
    --&gt;
    &lt;?php echo 'Our Little Church:'; ?&gt;" ?>
</code></pre>
```